# Can an oulet be added between two lights that are on the same switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I have lights on each side of my fireplace that are connected to one switch. I was wondering if it's possible to add outlet between the two lights so I can mount TV above fireplace?? Only power wire is the wire connecting the two lights. Power to that wire dies when the switch is shutoff.

Comment: Are you OK with the lights being on at all times when watching TV?   What's up with "TV above fireplace", how does the heat and soot not destroy it?

Comment: Could use smart bulbs so the light power is on all the time and a remote controls the lights.  And chances are the power wire goes up above the ceiling then over and down to the next light.  The wire might not go light-to-light like you are picturing.

Comment: TV above fireplace? Are you not afraid of TV's body deformation or another problem, caused by heat?

Comment: We don't use the fireplace for fires